# Logstash zabbix output

Tags: logstash, elasticsearch-plugin, zabbix, logstash-configuration, elastic-stack

This is my logstash.conf file. I am trying use logstash-output-zabbix plugin for alerting. But getting this error...

```
Field referenced by log_getter is missing {:level=>:warn}
```

I have a host named `ELK` in zabbix server with a `log_getter` item and `hello` as key (Zabbix trapper).

```
My config file...
input {
  lumberjack {
    port => 5000
    type => "logs"
    ssl_certificate => "/etc/pki/tls/certs/logstash-forwarder.crt"
    ssl_key => "/etc/pki/tls/private/logstash-forwarder.key"
  }
}

filter {
  grok {
    match => [ "message", "%{SYSLOGBASE} %{DATA:data}" ]
    add_tag => [ "zabbix-sender" ]
    add_field => [
      "zabbix_host", "%{source_host}",
      "zabbix_item", "item.key",
      "send_field", "data"
    ]
  }
}

output{
  elasticsearch{
    host => localhost
  }
}

output {
  zabbix {
    zabbix_host => "log_getter"
    zabbix_key =>"hello"
    zabbix_server_host => "10.0.30.215"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [zabbix plugin docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-outputs-zabbix.html#plugins-outputs-zabbix-zabbix_host) the plugin expects `zabbix_host =>` to contain a field name which holds the zabbix host name. Since you don't have any field called `log_getter` you get an error: `Field referenced by log_getter is missing`

Both, `zabbix_host` and `zabbix_key` expect the value to be a field reference. You've already set the values in your grok filter. Just use them in your output config:

```
zabbix {
    zabbix_host => "zabbix_host"
}
```

The `zabbix_key` value is not required. You can leave it out. Probably you will need to change your zabbix server configuration correspondingly to accept the events.

Comment: Thanks...it seems to work. How do I know on the zabbix server end that I am getting the messages. And Based on it how do I do alerting.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not a zabbix expert. I think you have to create a trapper item to receive the events. See the [zabbix docs](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/config/items/itemtypes/trapper) for more information. Maybe you could try the `zabbix_sender` command line tool to see if it works properly.

Comment: Explained properly https://discuss.elastic.co/t/logstash-with-zabbix-output-issue/1434/26?u=shivam_singh